# Can array of bytes be used as a key with CryptoJS.RC4.encrypt?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, cryptojs, rc4-cipher, symmetric-key

I need to use an array of bytes (non-printable characters) as a key for RC4 encryption. The plaintext is a string. It seems that `CryptoJS.RC4.encrypt` expects only strings for both plaintext and key.  Am I correct?  If not, how do I call `encrypt()` with string and array of bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a key value from a list of byte values, your best bet is to use the [hex encoder function, `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse`](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Encoders):

```
CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421');
```

This will parse your input string as a list of two-character pairs that each described a byte value. In this case, the hex values would be `48`, `65`, `6c`, `6c`, `6f`, etc. You can pass the result of the `parse` call directly into the encrypt/decrypt methods as the `key` parameter. (The result is a CryptoJS type called "`WordArray`," but you don't need to worry about the mechanics of this type; just pass it in as the key paramemter.)

If you want to transform an array of numbers to a hex string, you can do this easily with a simple loop and `.toString(16)`:

```
var byteArr = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44],
    str = "",
    byteVal;
for(var i=0; i<byteArr.length; i++) {
    byteVal = byteArr[i];
    if(byteVal < 16) { str += "0"; }
    str += byteVal.toString(16);
};
```

Comment: `byteArr.map((num) => (num < 16 ? '0' : '') + num.toString(16)).join('')`